# NiFi to Convert Folder to .ISO file

Tags: apache-nifi, converters, getfiles

I'm looking into a developing our current NiFi flow which helps transfer files over 2 domains using GetFile and PutFile. I have been asked to see if there is a way of building in a solution that will allow NiFi to convert a folder placed in the monitored share into a .ISO then transfer it to the remote domain so that the user can mount the .ISO as a drive.

Does anyone know of a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

NiFi doesn't inherently have that capability, but you can check out [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750614/how-to-generate-an-iso-with-jiic) and use ExecuteScript or InvokeScriptedProcessor to code it.

Comment: Hey MattyB thanks for the guidance. Sorry bit of a noob when it comes to bespoke NiFi processors, is there any guidance on the web on how to merge this script into a ExecuteScrip or InvokeScriptedProcessor? I love the idea just have no starting point on how to do this.